# Upcase alphabet

Tags: ruby

I can print the alphabet:

```
alphabet = 'A'..'Z'
```

I can convert strings into uppercase:

```
string.upcase
```

However, I can't figure out the right syntax to print the alphabet in uppercase.

The code below prints the alphabet capitalised, but the frequency does not work. When the alphabet is lowercase, it works.

```
s1 = @string
alphabet = 'A'..'Z'
mappedfreq = alphabet.collect do |s1|
  freq = @l1[s1]
  s1 + freq > 0 ? ": #{'* ' * freq}" : ''
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you store your alfphabet in all capital letters from the beginning, like this: `alphabet = ('A'..'Z')`, so you don't need to upcase it later?

Comment: I have done as you said, however when the alphabet is capitalised it stops the frequency from working? Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I've sorted it, just needed to convert the parsed string to uppercase aswell. Thanks Marek.

Comment: @JamesBurton so you can print an alphabet and convert a string to uppercase but somehow the frequency stops working. Don't you think that your question is lacking some information? What are you actually trying to do? What is your input, what is your output and how does your expected result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have created the range of alphabets is incorrect.

You should do it like this:

```
('a'..'z')
```

After that, Marek's solution will do the trick.

```
mappedfreq = alphabet.map(&:upcase).map do |s1|
  frq = @lt[s1]
  s1 + (frq> 0 ? ": #{'x ' x frq}" : '')
end
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over it (it is `Range`) and map it to upcase, like this:

```
mappedfreq = alphabet.map(&:upcase).map do |s1|
  frq = @lt[s1]
  s1 + (frq> 0 ? ": #{'x ' x frq}" : '')
end
```

I also see no reason that you can't store your alphabet in all capital letters in the first place, so that you wouldn't have to capitalize it:

```
alphabet = ('A'..'Z')
```

Comment: Hi, this works as far as converting the alphabet to uppercase, however it no longer adds the frequency to the letters. Thought it was due to you removing the ".collect" but that didn't seem to work either. Any ideas? Is it to to do with the second ".map"?

Comment: `map` and `collect` are aliases. Explain (in your question) what do you want this code to do.